# ssh work on command prompt but not on git-bash

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash

I am new to git. I am facing some issues in cloning a project through https, so after some research I decided to go through ssh and I am following [these instructions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html). I am working on Windows 7 64bit, and I have installed `Git-2.7.1-64-bit.exe` and ssh.

After installing I checked the ssh version in the command prompt with the command `ssh -v`. The command prompt (CMD) shows the proper version, but when I try the same command in git bash it does not show me any version at all. Here are screenshots of both:

cmd:
[image]

git bash:
[image]

So guys, please tell me what mistake I am making.

Comment: ...so, your "problem" is that your different shells have a different `ssh` implementations first in their respective PATHs? I'm not sure that's a thing that falls under the rubric of software development assistance (and thus our topic here).

Comment: That said, compare the output of `type ssh` in cygwin to the output of `where ssh` in cmd.exe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current version (`7.1p2` and many versions back) reacts to `-V` (uppercase `v`) to print version. The one which is installed out of your `git-bash` is really old and so behaves strange:

```
ssh -V
```

should do what you need.